# Play Application responses slowly on first request

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I have Play 2.4.6 application deployed on Ubuntu 16.04 (8GB RAM, 2 CPUs), using the "Running a production server in place" method (https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Production). I'm starting the server in a screen session with:

```
./app -J-Xms1000M -J-Xmx4000M -Dconfig.file=/home/play/app-prod.conf &
```

Everything works fine, but the very first request for a new "user" takes forever - around 1 to 2 minutes! After that it responses smoothly. But when I start a another browser, or a new private window the same effect occurs. But also not always, something is responses immediately. It is very strange. Initially I used Nginx as a proxy, but switched to Apache now, but the behavior remains. So the proxy works fine. 
Any idea what I could adjust or debug?

Comment: Did you have a look in your logs at all - anything look a bit suspect there? Since it's sporadic it might not necessarily be Play, In my experience, Nginx is usually very performant if configured correctly.

Comment: There is nothing suspicious in the logs. I checked them all, Nginx, Apache and Play.

Comment: Have you tried to hit different url's and see if that delay still happens (ex: "/", "/users", etc)? Also try to run the app without any proxy (if possible)? Also you can try to use `play.server.netty.log.wire = true` to see if you can get some debug info from there